# Export Lightning Component bundle

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I created some Lightning Components (*.cmp, *Controller.js, *Helper.js, *Controller.cls) and I wanted to export them to use them on other organisation.

How can I do this without taking care of Custom sObject ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 3 ways:

1. If your orgs are connected (sandboxes etc.), use a [changeset](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/app_deployment/app_deployment_changesets) between them.
2. Use [Force.com migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) (ant deploy).
3. Use one of the Force.com IDEs like [Eclipse](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) or [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/)

Comment: Thanks you @Itai.

No way possible using illuminated cloud on Intellij?

Comment: I am sure it is possible but I am not an expert on illuminated cloud so I don't really know how